# Select rows in data frame based all column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a python script that can take a dataframe of an arbitrary size and filter it for rows where any column matches some criteria, specifically looking for a text match. I show a 2x4 table to represent an example, but my data could have several thousand rows and anywhere from 1-15 columns.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Event1 | Event2 |
| Event2 | OPER-8 |
| OPER-1 | Event2 |
| Event3 | Event4 |

I want to basically filter the dataframe to give me the rows where any entry matches the phrase "OPER*" or maybe where "Event2" is present. Most of the ways I've found searching online require you to specify a column name/number, but I want to search the entire thing. I know I can do a for loop, but are there any ways to do this more efficiently with pandas?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a function on row axis of the dataframe to create True/False value for the provided condition, then take out the values based on this True/False value maksing

```py
>>> df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match('^OPER-\d+|Event2$').any(), axis=1)]
  A header Another header
0   Event1         Event2
1   Event2         OPER-8
2   OPER-1         Event2
```